# Do not run the job if it is already running

Tags: spring-batch, jobs, spring-batch-tasklet, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I am making a simple Sprint batch application that reads from a CSV file and writes it into the database. I want to throw an exception when we try to trigger a job that is already running. So before starting the job, I am checking if there is already a job running using this code

```
JobInstance lastJobInstance = jobExplorer.getLastJobInstance(job.getName());

        if (lastJobInstance != null) {
            List<JobExecution> runningExecutions = jobExplorer.getJobExecutions(lastJobInstance);

            for (JobExecution execution : runningExecutions) {
                if (execution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.STARTED  || execution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.STARTING) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Job is already running: " + job.getName());
                }

            }

        }
```

But In my DB (batch_job_execution table )i see an entry :

| job_execution_id | version | job_instance_id | create_time | start_time | end_time | status | exit_code | exit_message | last_updated | job_configuration_location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 1 | 13 | 2023-08-16 13:36:59.410 | 2023-08-16 13:36:59.459 |  | STARTED | UNKNOWN |  | 2023-08-16 13:36:59.459 |  |

This means that there was some Job that started but never completed and the reason for it is not known. Its exit code shows UNKNOWN. This job was run weeks ago it didn't fail nor completed (The reason is not known)
Also when a job has started and is currently going on its exit code also shows UNKNOWN.

I am not able to understand how to filter this job out and make sure to not run a job if it is already running.

So now whenever Im trying to run a new job it gives me "Job is already running" error because of this particular entry. Is there any way to filter out this entry because it is a very old entry and it might not get completed or failed ever

My DB [batch_job_execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggnDk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to throw an exception when we try to trigger a job that is already running

> I am not able to understand how to filter this job out and make sure to not run a job if it is already running.

This is done automatically by Spring Batch if you correctly define your job instances. In your example, if the input file is an identifying job parameters, running the same job instance will lead to a `JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException`. So there is no need to write the code you shared and manually check the existence of running executions.

Now if the job execution was abruptly terminated, then it is up to you to decide if you want to restart it or abandon it. In this case, you need to manually change its status in the database, see [Aborting a Job](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#aborting-a-job).

Comment: my jobParameter is the startTime `JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("startedAt", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();` which will never be same for 2 jobs hence the default handling by spring will rule out

Comment: The current time does not identify the input data for your batch job, so it is not a good choice for an identifying job parameter. You should carefully design job parameters to leverage Spring Batch's restartability feature, rather than having to write custom logic.

Comment: Hey I am having multiple parameters for the job one of them is the startTime so overall my parameters will never match. Is there a way we can do this without the parameters.